# IBM COGNOS incompatible data types in CASE / IF expression

Tags: informix, sqldatatypes, cognos-10

I have been trying for hours to get , what I thought to be, a simple if-then-else statement to work in IBM Cognos / Report Studio 10.0.
I am simply trying to create a data item in a query, to decide which day of the week a date is, and then return a calculated date.

```
if (cast(_day_of_week([Expected Delivery Date],1), integer) = 1) 
then (_add_days([Expected Delivery Date],2))
else (current_date)
```

The back end database is Informix. I am receiving the error "**Corresponding data types must be compatible in CASE expression or DECODE"**.

I have tried every variant I can think of: with/without cast, using case/when/then. I have created a separate data item also:

[Calc Day of Week] (Data Item - calculates correctly)

```
cast(_day_of_week([Expected Delivery Date],1), integer)
```

[Calc Exp Despatch Date] (Data Item)

```
if ([Calc Day of Week] = 1) 
then (_add_days([Expected Delivery Date],2))
else (current_date)
```

Even when using that data item in my next data item, I get the same error.

I can only think that it doesn't understand that I am basing the comparison on an integer and attempting to return a date - but if that is the case, how do I create a data item to perform such a calculation?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps when Cognos converts it to native Informix it messes it up? Can you try this using Informix-native functions?

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that the data types of the THEN and ELSE parts are different.  Your first step is to determine the data types.  You don't mention if you have done that with the calculations that you mention.  They seem to be concentrating on the IF part of the function.

The basic technique is called divide and conquer. A more elegant wording is, controlling the variables or isolating the components.

_day_of_week returns an int so I don't know why you are doing the casting.  (_day_of_week([Expected Delivery Date] = 1 ) should be sufficient but that's for later.

Take _add_days([Expected Delivery Date],2).  Put it into an expression and find out the data type which is returned.

Compare that data type with current_date.

Current_date returns a date.  What is the data type of expected delivery date? date or datetime?

If the data types are different then your approach would be to modify one or the other to match the other.   For example, cast _add_days([Expected Delivery Date],2) to date if it is a date time.  Or use current_timestamp but I don't use it so I can't speak much about it.

If you use 1=1 and 1<>1 in place of what you have for your if part then you can control the flow of the expression and verify that the error is coming from the then and else bits.

Here's something, for another application, but valid in outlining testing techniques.

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/corresponding-types-must-be-compatible-case-expression